# ADLS Gen 1 with Synapse Notebook Scala

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am not able to find the way to connect ADLS Gen 1 in a synapse notebook. I already have existing linked service for ADLS Gen 1. I have seen some of the documentation online but all are related to ADLS Gen 2. Please provide some help/references for connect and read csv/json from ADLS Gen 1 with synapse notebook using Scala.

I have found that mounting ADLS Gen 1 with mssparkutils is not supported in official document.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mount Gen1, but you can configure the connection directly in your notebook.  Here's an example using python, should be pretty easy to translate to scala. Replace anything within the fstring's with your actual values. For your clientid/secret, if you're storing that in keyvault you can use `mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret`

```
spark.conf.set(f"fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type","ClientCredential")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.adl.account.{gen1Account}.oauth2.client.id", f"{clientId}")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.adl.account.{gen1Account}.oauth2.credential", f"{clientSecret}")
spark.conf.set(f"fs.adl.account.{gen1Account}.oauth2.refresh.url", f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [Microsoft official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-migrate-gen1-to-gen2):

> **On Feb 29, 2024 Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 will be retired.** If you use Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, make sure to migrate to Azure
> Data Lake Storage Gen2 prior to that date.

Therefore there isn't any support available for your requirement, i.e., to mount the ADLS Gen 1 to synapse notebook.

The maximum you can do is:

1. You can load the data from ADLS Gen 1 storage to Dedicated SQL Pool using `Copy` statement. You can refer [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-data-lake-store) for the same.
2. You can link the ADLS Gen 1 with Azure synapse analytics and then perform the required operation on the stored files. Refer below image to link ADLS Gen 1 using Synapse Workspace.

[image]

I recommend you to [Migrate your data lake from Gen1 to Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-migrate-gen1-to-gen2) to avoid any issue in future.